# What is the ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can you please explain to me why in  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$,  $n\mathbb{Z}$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Can you please explain with some examples. I'm having trouble with what is ideal? Appreciate any help?

P.S. 
I've read a lot on the net about quotient rings but all are difficult to me to comprehend.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the fact that $n\mathbb Z$ is an ideal, or why all ideals in $\mathbb Z$ are of that form?

Comment: First write down the definition of an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$, and then check the axioms for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=n\mathbb{Z}$. In order to help you, you should say where exactly you get stuck there.

Comment: Can you please, explain with simple language what is the ideal is?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of an ideal is that it "acts as a stand-in for zero". In a ring (any ring) we have the following properties of $0$:

1. $0 + 0 = 0$
2. $a\cdot 0 = 0 \cdot a = 0$, for any $a$.

so an ideal is a subset $I$ of a ring $R$ for which:

1. $I + I = I$ (this means $I$ is *closed under addition*)
2. $RI = IR = I$ (this is called the *absorption property*).

Because some rings (in some texts) may not contain a multiplicative identity, one often sees (1.) above replaced by the condition:

1a. $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$, or the equivalent: $I$ is closed under subtraction.

Ideals are an example of what are called "kernels". These take different forms in different structures:

In groups, kernels are normal subgroups.

In abelian groups, kernels are subgroups.

In rings, kernels are ideals.

In vector spaces, kernels are null spaces.

Ring-homomorphisms are essentially "operation-preserving maps" that preserve sums and products:

$f: R \to S$ with $f(r + r') = f(r) + f(r')$ and $f(rr') = f(r)f(r')$.

It turns out the kernel of $f$:

$\text{ker }f = \{r \in R: f(r) = 0_S\}$ is such an ideal:

If $r,r' \in \text{ker }f$ then $f(r) = f(r') = 0_S$, and since $f$ preserves sums:

$f(r + r') = f(r) + f(r') = 0_S + 0_S = 0_S$, so that $r + r' \in \text{ker }f$

Similarly, for any $a \in R$ and $r \in \text{ker }f$, we have:

$f(ar) = f(a)f(r) = f(a)0_S = 0_S$, so that $ar \in \text{ker }f$. An analogous result holds for $ra$.

It turns out that ALL ideals arise in this way. To see this, given an ideal $I$, and a ring $R$, we somehow need to come up with another ring $S$ and a homomorphism $f$ with:

$f: R \to S$ and $\text{ker }f = I$.

This is how we can do this:

Call two elements $r_1,r_2 \in R$, "$I$-equivalent", if  $r_1 - r_2 \in I$.

It may not be obvious this is actually an equivalence relation on $R$, but we can show it like so:

$r$ is $I$-equivalent to itself (reflexiveness of $I$-equivalence):

$r - r = 0_R \in I$ (since any subgroup of $(R,+)$ contains the additive identity $0_R)$.

If $r$ is $I$-equivalent to $r'$, then $r'$ is $I$-equivalent to $r$ (symmetry of $I$-equivalence):

If $r - r' \in I$, then since $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$, we have:

$-(r - r') = r' - r \in I$.

If $r$ is $I$-equivalent to $r'$ and $r'$ is $I$-equivalent to $r''$, then $r$ is $I$-equivalent to $r''$ (transitivity of $I$-equivalence).

If we have $r - r' \in I$ and $r' - r'' \in I$, then since $I$ is closed under addition:

$r - r'' = (r - r') + (r' - r'') \in I$.

We call the SET of $I$-equivalence classes, the QUOTIENT SET $R/I$. It turns out that this can be made into a ring, like so:

Writing $[r]$ for the $I$-equivalence class of $r$, we set:

$[r] + [r'] = [r+r']$, and $[r][r'] = [rr']$.

WARNING!!! Although this seems "reasonable", we have to check that these definitions "make sense", that is, that they only depend on the equivalence classes, and not the individual elements of these classes. Let's do that now:

We need first to check that if $[r] = [a]$ and $[r'] = [b]$, that $[r + r'] = [a + b]$. So what we start with is:

$r - a \in I$ and $r' - b \in I$, and we need to show that $(r+r') - (a + b) \in I$.

But $(r + r') - (a + b) = (r - a) + (r' - b)$, which is the sum of two elements of $I$, and thus is in $I$, by closure.

We need to do the same for multiplication: given $r - a \in I$ and $r' - b \in I$, we need to show $rr' - ab \in I$.

This is a bit trickier:

$rr' - ab = rr' - rb + rb - ab = r(r' - b) + (r - a)b$. Now (using property 2), we have each term of this sum is in $I$, and thus the sum is.

This, then, makes the set of $I$-equivalences classes of $R$, a ring, the QUOTIENT RING of $R$ by $I$, $R/I$. We can then take $S = R/I$, and define our homomorphism $f: R \to R/I$ by $f(r) = [r]$. Then $\text{ker }f = [0_R] = I$.

---

Now, this may seem a bit "out-there". So let's use a very simple example:

We start with the ring of integers, $\Bbb Z$. We can, of course, form the subset $I = 2\Bbb Z$ of all *even* integers. I leave it to you to show that this is, in fact, an ideal (this comes down to showing the set of all even integers is a group under integer addition, and that multiplying an even integer by any other integer, still gives you an even integer).

Next, convince yourself that the *only* way $a - b$ can be even, is if BOTH $a,b$ are odd, or both are even. Thus we have just two $I$-equivalence classes, here:

$[0] = $ the even integers (this acts as the "zero of parity")

$[1] = $ the odd integers

and our ring operations are just the familiar rules:

odd + odd = even

even + odd = odd + even = odd

even + even = even

odd $\cdot$ odd = odd

odd $\cdot$ even = even $\cdot$ odd = even

even $\cdot$ even = even.

Answer (score 0):

**Some intuition:** 
When we do group theory, we are highly interested in subgroups as the main structure within a group, and especially normal subgroups. In rings, looking merely at sub-rings doesn't capture the structure very well, because it's too restrictive. Instead we study ideals.
Like normal subgroups, ideals arise naturally via kernels of homomorphisms. An ideal is the kernel of a ring homomorphism. As a result, the Isomorphism Theorems from group theory also apply to ring theory, using rings and ideals instead of groups and normal subgroups.

There's another, related context in which ideals appear, and that is in studying divisibility. Ideals were originally created to extend unique prime factorization to rings. In some rings, like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, our normal conception of factoring falls apart. $$6=2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$$ but all of the above numbers don't break up more. Mathematicians went looking for "ideal numbers" that behaved, in terms of divisibility, the way they wanted them to. Dedekind realized that you could define easily, instead of ideal numbers, the sets that they divide.

The concept of "being divided by" follows two important rules:

1. If some number (ideal or not) divides $a$ and $b$, it divided $a+b$.
2. If some number (ideal or not) divides $a$, it divdes $\lambda \times a$ for all $\lambda$.

So in the above example, it turns out that there is some "ideal number" $\alpha$ that divides both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ and a second "ideal number" $\beta$ that divides both $3$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$. The "ideal factorization" of $6$ turns out to be $\alpha^2\beta^2=6$ But since defining and proving existence of these "ideal numbers" is difficult and possibly philosophically problematic, it's much easier to talk about the *ideals* that they generate, i.e. their multiples

For every number, $z$ in a ring $R$, we can define the set of multiples of $z$ easily. This is called a principle ideal. We can also use the above two rules to produce ideals that are not just the multiples of any number (called non-principle ideals). These are the ideals that correspond to the multiples of "ideal numbers".

**Formally:**
An ideal, $I$, of a ring $R$ is a nonempty subset such that

1) $\forall x\in I, \forall r\in R, rx,xr\in I$

2) $\forall x,y\in I, x-y\in I$

In the case of $n\mathbb{Z}:=\{nz|z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ we see that $(nz)r=n(zr)$ and $(nz_1)-(nz_2)=n(z_1-z_2)$ so it satisfies these properties (and $0\in n\mathbb{Z}$ so it's nonempty)

Comment: Can you please, explain to me with more simple language, due to that fact that I've encountered as yours explanation in the papers and books ?

Comment: What about some examples?

Comment: @elgolondrino is this better